# Compound interest calculator loops

Tags: python, loops, calculator

Below is the code I have so far and the errors I am getting. I have tried playing but obviously I'm not understanding exactly how the loop should work

I am trying to loop so that wrong inputs i.e. alphabetical and under £1000 forces an error and re-input question. I have most of it working but it loops to initial question not error question on alphabetical input but gives error message then continues when using numerical but under £1000.

```
print ("Welcome to Trustees Investment Bank Compoud Interest Calculator") #Title
print ("Interest is calculated at 3.15% per annum")

while True:
    try:
        deposit2 = float(input("\nEnter initial deposit above £1000? ")) # Initial deposit amount
        rate = 0.0315 # interest rate
        if deposit2<1000:
            deposit2 = float(input("\nEnter initial deposit above £1000? ")) #loop   
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        break

for year in range(1,9):
    amount = deposit2 * (1.0 + rate) ** year
    print ("%4d%21.2f" % (year, amount))
```

This is my output

```
Welcome to Trustees Investment Bank Compound Interest Calculator
Interest is calculated at 3.15% per annum 
Enter initial deposit above £1000? jj 
Enter initial deposit above £1000? hgh 
Enter initial deposit above £1000? 500 
Not valid amount, 
please enter deposit above £1000 500 
1 515.75
2 532.00
3 548.75
4 566.04
5 583.87
6 602.26
7 621.23 
8 640.80
```

Comment: Post your code and errors here, not a screenshot

Comment: print ('Welcome to Trustees Investment Bank Compound Interest Calculator')#Title
print ('Interest is calculated at 3.15% per annum')
while True:
    try:
        deposit2 = float(input('Enter initial deposit above £1000? ')) #initial deposit amount
        rate = 0.0315  # interest rate
        if deposit2 <1000:     
            deposit2 = float(input('Not valid amount, please enter deposit above £1000 ')) #loop
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        break

Comment: for year in range( 1, 9 ):
    amount = deposit2 * ( 1.0 + rate ) ** year
    print ('%4d%21.2f' % ( year, amount ))

Comment: This is my output                                                                           
Welcome to Trustees Investment Bank Compound Interest Calculator
Interest is calculated at 3.15% per annum
Enter initial deposit above £1000? jj
Enter initial deposit above £1000? hgh
Enter initial deposit above £1000? 500
Not valid amount, please enter deposit above £1000 500
   1               515.75
   2               532.00
   3               548.75
   4               566.04
   5               583.87
   6               602.26
   7               621.23
   8               640.80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a while loop, therefore you don't need to ask for the user input twice. If the condition is not met, another iteration will happen and you will be asked for another input anyway. Also, your `else` is in the wrong place.

```
print ("Welcome to Trustees Investment Bank Compoud Interest Calculator")
print ("Interest is calculated at 3.15% per annum")

while True:
    try:
        deposit2 = float(input("\nEnter initial deposit above £1000? "))
        rate = 0.0315
        if deposit2<1000:
            print ("Not a valid amount, please try again.")
        else:
            break

    except ValueError:
        print ("You have not entered a number. Please enter a valid number")

for year in range(1,9):
    amount = deposit2 * (1.0 + rate) ** year
    print ("%4d%21.2f" % (year, amount))
```

This has the output:

```
Welcome to Trustees Investment Bank Compoud Interest Calculator
Interest is calculated at 3.15% per annum

Enter initial deposit above £1000? 50
Not a valid amount, please try again.

Enter initial deposit above £1000? abcdefg
You have not entered a number. Please enter a valid number

Enter initial deposit above £1000? 1500
   1              1547.25
   2              1595.99
   3              1646.26
   4              1698.12
   5              1751.61
   6              1806.79
   7              1863.70
   8              1922.41
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes more sense now couldn't figure out where i was wrong. Now I can see what was happening. still learning.

Comment: @Christopher No problem :) If this answer solved your problem then don't forget to upvote and accept it to mark as solved